# How can I change the name of the VBScript process, wscript.exe?

Tags: process, rename, vbscript

I want to run multiple scripts simultaneously, but monitoring them or detecting which has died is difficult as they are all listed as `wscript.exe` in the process list.

How can I change the name of the running process?

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of is to make a copy of wscript.exe for each script you need to have a unique name in process explorer then explicitly call that copy.

For example say you have renamer.vbs create a copy of wscript.exe and call it renamer.exe

Now run your script like:

```
...\renamer.exe renamer.vbs
```

You process should show up as renamer.exe

Comment: Cheers, I didn't see this answered on SU and was intending adding the solution as per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.  You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the script is running locally then you can copy wscript.exe, renaming it to whatever you like then call this from a shortcut.

For example, if you wanted to show the process as `WorldsBestScript.exe` then you would call  it like this

`WorldsBestScript.exe TheActualScript.vbs`

[image: Properties screenshot]

The above assumes you've copied `wscript.exe` to the same folder as the VBS file, if it is anywhere else then you'd obviously have to include the full path to `WorldsBestScript.exe`